# Unable to persist data into many-to-many mapping entity

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have 2 entities - `Book` and `Publisher` which have a many-to-many relationship. Besides the ids of these entities in the mapping entity, I want to store additional attribute such as bookFormat. So I created a mapping entity `BookPublisher` and created a composite key entity `BookPublisherId`. Now, when I want to persist the data using JSON data from my rest controller, I am not able to persist the data correctly. In my JSON data, I am passing the following:

```
{
    "name": "Book14",
    "authors": [
        {
            "firstName": "book14FirstName",
            "lastName": "book14LastName"
        }
    ],
    "publishers": [
        {
            "publisher": {
                "name": "Pearson1"
            },
            "format": "Paperback"
        }   
    ]
}
```

Here's the `Book` entity:

```
@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Set<Author> authors;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book")
    private List<Review> reviews;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book")
    private Set<BookPublisher> publishers;


    public Book() {

    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Review> getReviews() {
        return reviews;
    }

    public void setReviews(List<Review> reviews) {
        this.reviews = reviews;
    }

    public Set<Author> getAuthors() {
        return authors;
    }

    public void setAuthors(Set<Author> authors) {
        this.authors = authors;
    }

    public Set<BookPublisher> getPublishers() {
        return publishers;
    }

    public void setPublishers(Set<BookPublisher> publishers) {
        this.publishers = publishers;
    }

}
```

Here's the `Publisher` entity:

```
@Entity
public class Publisher {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "publisher")
    private Set<BookPublisher> publishedBooks;

    public Publisher() {
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<BookPublisher> getPublishedBooks() {
        return publishedBooks;
    }

    public void setPublishedBooks(Set<BookPublisher> publishedBooks) {
        this.publishedBooks = publishedBooks;
    }
}
```

Here's the `BookPublisher` entity:

```
@Entity
public class BookPublisher {

    @EmbeddedId
    private BookPublisherId bookPublisherId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("bookId")
    private Book book;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("publisherId")
    private Publisher publisher;

    private String format;

    public BookPublisher() {
    }

    public BookPublisher(Book book, Publisher publisher, String format) {
        this.book = book;
        this.publisher = publisher;
        this.format = format;
    }

    public BookPublisherId getBookPublisherId() {
        return bookPublisherId;
    }

    public void setBookPublisherId(BookPublisherId bookPublisherId) {
        this.bookPublisherId = bookPublisherId;
    }

    public Book getBook() {
        return book;
    }

    public void setBook(Book book) {
        this.book = book;
    }

    public Publisher getPublisher() {
        return publisher;
    }

    public void setPublisher(Publisher publisher) {
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }

    public String getFormat() {
        return format;
    }

    public void setFormat(String format) {
        this.format = format;
    }
}
```

Here's the code where I am trying to save the `Book` entity I receive in the rest controller:

```
 public Book addBook(Book book) {
        Set<BookPublisher> toAddPublishers = new HashSet<>();
        for(BookPublisher publisher : publishers) {
            Publisher addedPublisher = publisherRepository.save(publisher.getPublisher());
            BookPublisher toAddBookPublisher = bookPublisherRepository.save(new BookPublisher(book, addedPublisher, publisher.getFormat()));
            toAddPublishers.add(toAddBookPublisher);
        }
        book.setPublishers(toAddPublishers);
        Book addedBook = bookRepository.save(book);
        return addedBook;
    }
```

When I try to call this method, I see that the `BookPublisher` entity is not being persisted in the database. What is the correct way to add such data?

Answer (score 0):

I can not say anything definite by the looks of your code but is your `addBook` inside a transactional scope? Also, why have you not set any cascades for your relationships?